# Formik ReactBoostrap Form not validating

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik, yup

I have formik form build on the react-boostrap form. I have a custom onchange for handling the inputs. The issue is that validation error throw even if there is a value in the form field. Also, If some value is typed then error message is not gone. I guess the validation is not working at all. Please help me on this.

This is the code for react-bootstrap form https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries

```
import React from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default function StepByStepForm() {
  const [myForm, setMyForm] = useState({});

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    setMyForm((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const form1schema = yup.object({
    company_name: yup.string().required(),
  });

  function Step1Form() {
    return (
      <Formik validationSchema={form1schema}>
        {({
          touched,
          isValid,
          isInvalid,
          errors,
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          values,
          validateForm,
        }) => (
          <Form noValidate className="formstep1">
            <Form.Group controlId="addCompany">
              <Form.Label>Company Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="company_name"
                type="text"
                value={myForm.company_name}
                onChange={handleInput} // have my custom handling
                isInvalid={!!errors.company_name}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.company_name}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <div className="step-progress-btn">
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => validateForm()}>
                Validate
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }

  return <div>Step1Form()</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `onChange={handleInput}` function never passes the value to Formik.

Formik internally keeps track of your form values, so you don't need to add it using the `useState` method like you are now (`const [myForm, setMyForm] = useState({});`).

When you add a custom `onChange` to your form, you change your component state, while Formik's state never updates, so Yup does not have a value to validate.

If you add this just below your closing `</Form>` tag, you will see Formik never reads your form's updated values:

```
<pre>
  {JSON.stringify(
    {
      touched,
      isValid,
      isInvalid,
      errors,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      values,
      validateForm
    },
    null,
    2
  )}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Formik-Yup needed the onChange={handleChange} to validate

If you have custom or additional functionality on top of handleChange then you need to add the eventlistener on top of handlechange

```
import React from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default function StepByStepForm() {
  const [myForm, setMyForm] = useState({});

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;
    setMyForm((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const form1schema = yup.object({
    company_name: yup.string().required(),
  });

  function Step1Form() {
    return (
      <Formik validationSchema={form1schema}>
        {({
          touched,
          isValid,
          isInvalid,
          errors,
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          values,
          validateForm,
        }) => (
          <Form noValidate className="formstep1">
            <Form.Group controlId="addCompany">
              <Form.Label>Company Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="company_name"
                type="text"
                value={myForm.company_name}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e);
                  handleInput(e);
                }}
                isInvalid={!!errors.company_name}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.company_name}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <div className="step-progress-btn">
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => validateForm()}>
                Validate
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }

  return <div>Step1Form()</div>;
}
```